How can we deal with unanswered questions?
Something noticeable about the unanswered questions is that the majority of questions (19 out of 23) relate to the robotics software and hardware. 
Do we have too few experts on this subject, are theses questions too specific or is there some other reason?

I'd say that most of the truly unanswered ones are very specialised: either skiing for help with a specific error that perhaps out haven't seen or using some combination of set ups that are fairly unique ("How can I control nxt 2.0 robot with a Wiimote in labview?", "Guide me on how to use my Mindstorm RCX kit on OS X Mavericks") - perhaps these should be closed as too localised. Others seem to be suffering from the fact we're not a discussion site something's not working some suggestions have been made and then there's no further response from the OP. 
